# Do something when my WCF service started

Tags: c#, wcf, startup

I want to do something  just after my WCF service started. How can do it?

In fact,I should update some variable of my service every 10 minutes. So I put my update code in a thread. But I dont know how start this thread when service started (Is there anything liked Form_Load event in WCF services?)

Comment: How do you host your wcf service?

Answer (score 5):

There is typically no parts of your WCF service that is "just hanging around" in memory ready to do something.... WCF is **NOT** ASP.NET !

The default setup when hosting in IIS is this:

- IIS listens on a specific port/URL for a request - there's not a single trace of your WCF service anywhere in memory
- when a first request comes in, IIS will spin up a `ServiceHost` - a class that can "host" a service
- this service host will then look at the request has come in and depending on the target URL, it will decide which service class to instantiate to handle this request. The service class (your service implementation) is then created and the appropriate method on that service class is called and executed, and once that's completed, the service class is disposed

So basically, there are two points where you can hook into:

1. you could create your own custom `ServiceHost` class that will do something when it gets instantiated
2. you can add some "initialization" code to each of your service class methods to handle your needs

Comment: What about other types of hosting? This is IIS specific. In Win service hosting, for example, OP can create a timer and use a tick event to do that.

Comment: @oleksii: when you self-host, yes, you have a bit more control - but still - you basically can tweak the service host which gets instantiated under your control, or you do something in the service method, when it's called

Comment: What should someone do then if they want something "just hanging around" in memory?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to keep a thread running on a server. As soon as the last session terminates the application shuts down. Some hosting providers also recycle the app pool on a schedule which kills any chance of keeping a thread running.

That aside, WCF Services don't actually run. They act like web pages triggered by a request. The sensible place to add init code would be in your `Application_Start` in `Global.asax`. This would get called once when the application starts (the first request is made).

If you would rather do something on each request to your services, you could hook the `Application_BeginRequest` event also in `Global.asax`.

Comment: What if he hosts WCF in a Windows service or in a self-hosted application? There is no global.asax there and it doesn't act as a web application in that sense. Plus WCF may not use sessions at all.

Comment: Good point it does depend on hosting, I assumed website but either of those could be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instanced service, which will call the constructor upon the start of your service:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class InstanceService
{
    private int _intValue;

    public InstanceService()
    {
        _intValue = 456;
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public int GetData()
    {
        return _intValue;
    }
}
```

Invoking GetData() on this service will return an integer with a value of 456.

Comment: Such a singleton service instance has two major drawbacks: 1) it either serializes the requests and handles one after another, creating a potentially massive bottleneck - or 2) it requires fully multi-threading aware programming, something that's not easy at all and quite error-prone. I would try to avoid singletons whenever possible

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention that this'll only be useful in very specific situations, and isn't something that should be considered easily.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved if you are able to control how to host this. If you can, host your WCF service as a Windows service or an ad hoc executable. Then you can achieve what you want with ease. If you are bound to IIS hosting you must do as others have suggested and handle it per request.

Read up on self hosting wcf if IIS is not required.